# How to manage Chef cookbook in Git which has a dependent cookbook

Tags: git, chef-infra

It seems like a basic question probably but I'm just not sure how to use `git` for my chef repo. I have a chef repo which contains 2 cookbooks:
`chef_docker_test` and `docker`.

```
 ~/chef-repo
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── cookbooks
    ├── chef_docker_test
    │   ├── Berksfile
    │   ├── Berksfile.lock
    │   ├── LICENSE
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── chefignore
         ...

    ├── docker
    │   ├── CHANGELOG.md
    │   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── libraries
    │   │   ├── docker_base.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_container.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_exec.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_image.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_installation_package.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_installation_script.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_installation_tarball.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_network.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_registry.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_base.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_manager_execute.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_manager_systemd.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_manager_sysvinit_debian.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_manager_sysvinit_rhel.rb
    │   │   ├── docker_service_manager_upstart.rb
  ...
```

Most of the time it seems that people use one git repo for each cookbook. I wanted to follow this approach too. But my `chef_docker_test` repo fails when I just clone it and try to run. This is because this repo has a dependency on the `docker` cookbook from the marketplace. What is the recommended way to manage this? Do I have to put 2 cookbooks in one git repo or just leave the dependency and install it when I start my `chef_docker_test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would generally use Berkshelf or the Policyfile tools to manage dependencies, just like you use Bundler for Ruby or Pip requirements/pipfile for Python. You would need to be more specific about "try to run" for a precise answer though. Test Kitchen includes direct support for both, as does ChefSpec. For interfacing with Chef Server, you do uploads through the relevant tool, or for solo you use the export/vendor command to dump a folder in the correct structure for chef-solo.